# Dict vs custom structure when direct access is not needed?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

When you have to store some key-value pairs that need to be iterated, but never directly accessed, i.e. you will never have to call `dict.get(key)` or `dict[key]`. Is it still best to use python dict or it may be the case to create a custom structure in favor of syntax sugar for when manipulating the structure.

```
# pairs: <class Rule>:<list <class Verb>>

# dict manipulation
for rule, methods in rules_dict.iteritems():
    for method in methods:
        do_something(rule, method)

# structure manipulation
for rule in rules_struct.rules:
    for method in rule.methods:
        do_something(rule, method)
```

My main concern is that despite I prefer manipulating the structure it may be (this is what I am not so sure about) bad to create some custom classes inheriting `Rule` and `Verb` and then have to go on converting `Rule` to `MyStruct.Rule` and `Verb` to `MyStruct.Verb` when building structure instances.

Comment: If you are looking for a dictionary that maps keys on lists of values, take a look at [`MultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict).

Comment: Just use tuples? `(1, [1, 2, 3])`

Comment: If you're looking for syntax sugar, maybe you should think about moving the do_something piece of code inside the "Rule" class and making the "methods" (class Verb) a field inside the Rule class? By the way, I don't think that you want to use a custom class. On the other hand, have you considered why you're using a dict instead of a tuple if you're not updating your keys?

Comment: @Coldspeed Indeed, easier and better than both options I had come up with. Thanks.